# How do I calculate SUM(DISTINCT field1) - COUNT (field2)?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I need to calculate `RESULT = SUM(DISTINCT field1) - COUNT (field2)` for a group in a SSRS 2005 report.

`DISTINCT` is not allowed in SSRS and if I omit `DISTINCT` the `SUM` is too high (I have field2 which occurs multiple times within field1).

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539438/ssrs-sumdistinct-equivalent?

Comment: field1 and field2 are from the same table?

Comment: field1 and field2 are from different tables

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread, but I hope it help others!

You need to write custom code to apply the aggregate.

For full reference and code please take a look at this post and the answer within the comments section [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bwelcker/archive/2005/05/10/416306.aspx#6799201).